inductive sin cos position sensor EMC considerations
I am studying the use of an linear inductive sensor of approximately 250mm movement.
Available IC's include TI LDC5072, Renesas IPS2550 and others.
Reference https://www.celeramotion.com/inductive-sensors/support/technical-papers/inductive-sensors/ 
EMC considerations on these designs are unclear, I'm unable to find much info on this.
What prevents the resonant frequency of the tx drive coil from radiating at that frequency?  Is it ultimately my understanding of what it couples to to prevent this jumping to a ground plane and out some external wire somewhere?  Or what could be other considerations of how this works?
In this case, the drive TX track would have to be somewhere around 25mm x 300mm outer size.

Resonance does not necessarily mean excessive EMI. Why do you think it should?

Because this can be tricky.  After one or two passes at a lab this stuff gains clarity that I don't presently have.  Add a leg to this coil, couple it to the wrong thing, it probably makes a nice little AM radio, the way I understand it.


What prevents the resonant frequency of the tx drive coil from
radiating at that frequency?

Nothing, you will need shielding if it is a problem for your application. Buy one and get a near field probe and probe it for 1-10MHz and see if it radiates.
If you notice in the link, the housed encoders prevent EMI.

The main roles of the housing in an encoder are to provide protection
from EMI and interference due to nearby metal. The housing serves as a
Faraday Cage, which blocks external electric fields.
The housing will protect from interference of nearby metal. Hence,
there are not any requirements on the installation location of the
IncOder since the performance will not be affected. This provides an
ease of installation
Source: https://www.celeramotion.com/inductive-sensors/support/technical-papers/housed-vs-unhoused-encoders/

So if you wanted to prevent EMI, you would need some kind of shielding

The simple thing to do is taking an eval kit or whatever you have that is close enough to your application and go do a preliminary scan at your local emi lab.
I did that for a sensor like that and it passed with a lot of margin (no enclosure).
Had it not passed, my next attempt would be to move the tx frequency to one of the ISM bands and call it an intentional transmitter. That would give a lot more room for emissions.
